# Substituir elementos de uma matriz por um "X"

Tags: python-3.x, lista, matriz

Possuo código que deverá imprimir uma matriz de acordo com a entrada.

Deverá imprimir a matriz fazendo com que o "X" forme uma espiral para a direita começando do meio, alguém tem alguma ideia?

ps.:Os comentários do código são as tentativas

```
while True:
tamanho = int(input())
if tamanho in range(1, 25):
    tabela = []
    for x in range(0, tamanho):
        tabela.append(["O"]*tamanho)
    for y in tabela:
        print("".join(y))
        '''tabela[(len(tabela)+1)/2] = "X"
        posicao_do_x = len(tabela)/2
        posicao_do_x2 = int(posicao_do_x) // int(y)
        posicao_do_x3 = int(posicao_do_x) % int(y)
        tabela[int(posicao_do_x2)][int(posicao_do_x3)] = "X"'''
    print("@")
else:
    break
```

Comment: Tem como desenhar um exemplo de como seria a saída? Está um pouco difícil entender exatamente o que seria uma "espiral para a direita começando no meio".

Comment: Seria semelhante a [isso](http://ideone.com/RKKBlp)?

Comment: Vc quer fazer uma espiral de Ulam?